# Admob interstitial ad delegate

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I am trying to assign a delegate to admob interstitial ad so i can handle ad events.

The GADInterstitialDelegate implementing class:

```
class AdDelegate: NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate
{
//Interstitial delegate
func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    println("interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError:\(error.localizedDescription)")

}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    println("interstitialDidReceiveAd")

}

func interstitialWillDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    println("interstitialWillDismissScreen")

}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    println("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
}

func interstitialWillLeaveApplication(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    println("interstitialWillLeaveApplication")
}

func interstitialWillPresentScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    println("interstitialWillPresentScreen")
}
```

}

The assign of the delegate to the ad:

```
add.delegate = AdDelegate()
```

The problem is that the ad events are not fired inside the AdDelegate implementing class (the ad is shown properly) any idea why?

I cant implement the GADInterstitialDelegate in the same class as the assign to the ad object becasue the ad object is created in class func which give compiler error

Comment: GADInterstitialDelegate is not found on the version 9.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GADInterstitial delegate is a weak stored property, so you should create a stored property in your class:

```
var adDelegate : AdDelegate? // to store the delegate 

func createInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial()
    interstitial.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6938332798224330/6206234808";
    adDelegate = AdDelegate()
    interstitial.delegate = adDelegate //delegate is weak so we need to store the property

    return interstitial
}
```

Please look at the documentation to better understand how ARC works https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: You just saved me, thanks a lot!